# Is it possible to aggregate a join as a comma seperated list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table Users, and a table Phone.

A user can have multiple phone numbers. So the return of a join might look like this:

```
|   name   |  phonenr    |
|----------|-------------|
|  Eve     |  00123      |
|  Eve     |  00145      |
|  Eve     |  00125      |
|  Eve     |  00245      |
|  Bob     |  00147      |
|  Bob     |  00159      |
|  Bob     |  00258      |
```

However this creates many similar rows, because a user can have so many rows. Is it possible to return something like this:

```
|   name   |          phonenr            |
|----------|-----------------------------|
|  Eve     |  00123, 00145, 00125, 00245 |
|  Bob     |  00147, 00159, 00258        |
```

I am using Linq and Entity Framework 6 though. My query looks something like this:

```
(from user in context.Users
 orderby user.Id
 select new User{
     id = user.id,
     name = user.name,
     phonenr = (from nr in context.Phone
                where nr.userid.Equals(user.id)
                select nr.Number).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't EF give you a `Phones` navigation property you can use instead of that subquery?

Comment: Kind of. But when I look at the query that gets executed to the DB it still generates a lot of clutter because of this. Keep in mind that this is a simple query, which is just used as an example to for my post. The real query has a ton of lists like this. So when I normally get around 30 items, it still generates more than 5000 results in the end because of all these lists

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the name and aggregate, but I'd do that in memory as it won't translate into SQL via EF.  Also you should have a `Phones` navigation property you can use instead of doing a sub-query on the phone table.

```
var results = (from user in context.Users
               from phone in user.Phones
               orderBy user.Id
               group phone.Number by user into g
               select new {
                   g.Key.Id,
                   g.Key.Name,
                   Phones = g.ToList()})
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(x => new User{
                   Id = x.Id,
                   Name = x.Name,
                   Phones = string.Join(",", x.Phones)})
              .ToList();
```

Comment: why are you grouping on phonenumber?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It's grouping the phone number by the user.

Comment: alright.. makes sense now, never thought it can be done  this way

Comment: The problem is that this will not be translated to SQL. So the database response will still be very slow

Comment: @user2657943 I doubt a sql query that would do the string manipulation would be any faster